# File templates not showing up

Tags: xcode, file, cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode6

I'm trying to add a new class. I select Cocoa Class and set it as a Subclass of: UITableViewController. But here's the problem; the .m file is like a regular viewController, it doesn't have all those tableView things. This is everything in the file: http://gyazo.com/699b8f93956659cbfeec69f4d27d7f11

It worked last week

Any guesses? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the method you want, it doesn't matter that it is blank or not.

Maybe you want to create new file with some original method likes: `- (void)viewDidLoad` or `- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning`.

When create new file, choose the subclass you want.Then Xcode will finish the stuff.

Comment: When I create a new file, i do select UITableViewController, but XCode wont fill inn the stuff; http://gyazo.com/a20fcb01983a4cf33212513e96f36fda

Comment: Are you creating Cocoa Touch Class in iOS?